# SQL Query executed successfully but data won't show

Tags: javascript, php, html

This code works on localhost, but in cpanel dont. I cannot access to $row and columns from it.
`print_r($row)` prints all the values correctly but when I try to use like `$row['name']` it returns me null
`alert($row['name'])` is not showing

Code:

```
<?php 
                    
include './sql/connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT id, name, category, price, description, image FROM proizvod";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<script>alert(".$row['name'].")</script>";
    if($row['category']=='Nargila')
        $category = 'filter-narg';
    else if($row['category']=='Ukus')
        $category = 'filter-ukusi';
    else if($row['category']=='Ostalo')
        $category = 'filter-ostalo';

    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 shop-item '. $category .'">
        <div class="product shadow-lg rounded-2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <a href="shop-details.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="./assets/img/shop/'. $row['image'] .'" class="img-fluid" alt="'. $row['description'] .'">
                    <div class="social">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-xs me-2"></i>Više
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info mt-1 py-2">
                <span>'. $row['category'] .'</span>
                <h4>'. $row['name'] .'</h4>
                <h3 class="mt-3">'. $row['price']-1 .' RSD</h3>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="./pages/delete.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" onclick="return confirm(\'Da li si siguran da hoćeš da izbriseš?\')" 
                class="btn btn-primary-outline text-danger mb-2 admin">Izbriši</a>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input name="id" type="text" class="d-none" value="'. $row['id'] .'">
                <button class="btn w-100 py-3 bg-theme" name="add-to-cart" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-plus fa-xl me-3"></i>Dodaj u korpu
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

How to access to that values?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the argument to `alert()`: ```alert('".$row['name']."')```

Comment: Your browser console should be full of error messages saying that you're accessing undefined variables. Didn't you see them when you were debugging this?

Comment: Now alert works and it return me the right data, i dont have an idea why $row['name'] won't show in echo where is html code

Comment: Try putting parentheses around `$row['price']-1` because `-` has higher precedence than `.`.

Comment: Thank you, it was all about the parentheses hahaha xD